# How to deal with "IN" in WHERE-clause in Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Here is the dql-query

```
$dql = "SELECT t Entities\Table t WHERE t.field IN (?1)";
    $q = $em->createQuery($dql)
                ->setParameter(1, '108919,108920');
    $result = $q->execute();
```

if i pass parameters through setParameter doctrine returns only first result, but if i put them directly into the dql-query it returns 2 results (this is correct):

```
$dql = "SELECT t Entities\Table t WHERE t.field1 IN (108919,108920)";
```

How to deal with "IN" in WHERE-clause through setParameter?

Answer (score 9):

Be aware that this only works for numbered parameters, and not named parameters.

```
$searchParameters = array(108919, 108920);

$dql = "SELECT t Entities\Table t WHERE t.field IN (?1)";
$q = $em->createQuery($dql)
   ->setParameter(1, $searchParameters);

$result = $q->execute();
```

Comment: I was tearing my hair out trying to figure out why I couldn't get array parameters to work - replacing named parameter with numbered saved my day :-)

Comment: I just came across this question and tried it with a named parameter anyway. Seems like somewhere between this answer and now, Doctrine was changed to allow this construction for named parameters as well.

Answer (score 6):

The following should work fine:

```
$searchParameters = array(108919, 108920);

$dql = "SELECT t Entities\Table t WHERE t.field IN (?1)";
$q = $em->createQuery($dql)
   ->setParameter(1, $searchParameters);

$result = $q->execute();
```

You can pass in an array, without using implode() and doctrine will handle it properly (as a list of integers).

Note: if you're already working with the string '108919, 108920' -- you will need to use the explode and trim functions.

This is also mentioned here: [How to use the in statement in DQL in Doctrine 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057285/how-to-use-the-in-statement-in-dql-in-doctrine-2-0)

Comment: This works for me and thus I would assume is the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work as expected (for an arbitrary numer of arguments to the `IN` clause)

```
$params = array(1 => 108919, 2 => 108920);
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select(array('t'))
   ->from('Entities\Table', 't')
   ->where($qb->expr()-> in('t.field', array_map(function($p) { return '?'.$p; }, array_keys($params)))
   ->setParameters($params);
$q = $qb->getQuery();
$r = $q->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 :

```
$dql = "SELECT t Entities\Table t WHERE t.field IN (?1, ?2)";
$q = $em->createQuery($dql)
->setParameters(array(1 =>'108919', 2 => '108920'));
$result = $q->execute();
```

Solution 2 (more elegant) :

```
$parameters = array(1 =>'108919', 2 => '108920');
$dql = 'SELECT t Entities\Table t WHERE t.field IN (?'.implode(', ?', array_keys($parameters)).')';
$q = $em->createQuery($dql)
->setParameters($parameters);
$result = $q->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
public function searchCategory($target){

      $query = $this->getEntityManager()
                    ->createQuery("SELECT ct.id as id,ct.name as name, ct.target as target FROM LoveThatFitAdminBundle:ClothingType ct WHERE ct.target IN (:target)")
                     ->setParameter('target',$target['target']);
                     try {
                     return $query->getResult();
                } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
                return null;
                }

 }
```