# How to use the in statement in DQL in Doctrine 2.0

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have the following query that uses an IN statement.

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$query = 'select o from Organisation o where o.id in (:ids)';
$this->_entityManager->createQuery($query)
            ->setParameter('ids', implode(', ', $ids))
```

Doctrine is not returning any results, I think it is because of something wrong in the conversion that Doctrine does for the passed parameter `$ids` which is an array.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 54):

Try passing the array itself to `->setParameter(...)` instead of imploding it into a string.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I had the same problem and `->setParameter('ids', $ids)` does work

Answer (score 2):

I used this (setParameter didn't seem to work for me):

```
$em->createQuery('SELECT users FROM Entities\User users WHERE users.id IN (:ids)')
->setParameters(array('ids' => $ids));
```

http://redbeardtechnologies.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/doctrine-2-dql-in-statement/

Answer (score 2):

I solved this:

```
$con = $this->getEntityManager();
$query = $con->createQuery("SELECT cl
                            FROM BackendBundle:classifieds cl 
                            INNER JOIN BackendBundle:locations lo WITH cl.locationId = lo.id
                            INNER JOIN BackendBundle:municipality mu WITH lo.municipalId = mu.id
                            WHERE cl.verified = false AND mu.id = ".$munId." AND cl.locationId NOT IN (:ids) ");
$query->setParameters(array('ids' => $locsIds));
return $query->getResult();
```

Comment: If you need multiple parameters:

$query->setParameters(array('ids' => $locsIds, 'munIds' => $munIds));

and the query will look's like this:

..... WHERE cl.locationId NOT IN (:ids) AND mu.id NOT IN (:munIds)

Answer (score -1):

I'm struggling with the IN statement too, using the $query->expr()->in() construct...

Try:

```
$em->createQuery(“SELECT users FROM Entities\User users WHERE users.id IN (':ids')”)
->setParameters(array(‘ids’ => $ids));
```

I think the simple quotes around your parameters in the IN() part are necessary...