# Doctrine2 DQL where id in array

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a user and I want to check if it is in the qstn users relationship.
I tried to execute the following DQL:

```
SELECT exmpl, qstn
    FROM Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Examples exmpl
    LEFT JOIN exmpl.question qstn
    LEFT JOIN qstn.users u
    WHERE :user IN (qstn.users)
```

But gave me the an error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 391: Error: Expected Literal, got 'qstn'
```

Is this even possible? If no, is there a work around (the doctrine way), not to nasty?
(Not passing the users pre handed I could figure that out).

For ex NOT this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22230515/2535171

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't seem to make sense.  Is there a user's table?  How does that connect? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you can use the DQL keyword "MEMBER OF" ex:

```
SELECT exmpl, qstn
   FROM Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Examples exmpl
   LEFT JOIN exmpl.question qstn
   LEFT JOIN qstn.users u
   WHERE :user MEMBER OF qstn.users
```

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You just need one more join

```
SELECT exmpl, qstn
FROM Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Examples exmpl
LEFT JOIN exmpl.question qstn
LEFT JOIN qstn.users u
WHERE u.id = :userID
```

Comment: So? you now compare for a single ID, I need multiple with the 'IN' (array).

Comment: no, if only one of `qstn.users` `id` equals `:userID`, `exmpl` will be selected.