# Search with Symfony and Doctrine in Many To Many Relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

i'm learning symf4 and doctrine and i have a little question about search with doctrine in many to many relation between table.

I have User, Skills and Moods Entity.

User:

```php
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Mood")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="user_mood",
     *  joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="mood_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *  inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $moods;

/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Skill")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="user_skill",
     *  joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="skill_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *  inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $skills;
```

Is all Ok in my db, i have pivot table etc etc, but now i want to "Search" all User with some skills and some moods, something like this as payload:

```php
$mood = ['test','test1'];
$skill = ['skillTest'];
```

I'm trying to retrieve all User with at leasy 1 of each of this parameters.

Here my code:

```php
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('u')
            ->from('App:User', 'u')
            ->where('u.deletedAt is null')
            ->andWhere('u.status = :status');

        $qb->leftJoin('App:Mood', 'm')
                    ->andWhere('m.title IN (:moodArray)')->setParameter('moodArray', $params['mood']);

        $qb->setParameter('status', $status)
            ->orderBy('u.createdAt', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->setFirstResult($offset);
```

but i have this error, using LEFT JOIN

```php
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE u0_.status = 'ONLINE' AND m1_.title IN ('test' at line 1"
```

If i use only JOIN, i retrieve all user, and is not my final target :b 
Any advice? thx a lot

EDIT: 
I change my "code" with this and the result is always empty array, with LEFT JOIN or JOIN always [] U,U

```php
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('u')
            ->from('App:User', 'u')
            ->where('u.deletedAt is null')
            ->andWhere('u.status = :status');

        $qb->leftJoin('u.moods', 'm')
                    ->andWhere('m.title IN (:moodArray)')->setParameter('moodArray', $params['mood']);

        $qb->setParameter('status', $status)
            ->orderBy('u.createdAt', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->setFirstResult($offset);
```

Comment: A likely source of your problem is in your `$params['mood']` array. What does that look like? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057285/how-to-use-the-in-statement-in-dql-in-doctrine-2-0) for hints.

Comment: "mood" => array:2 [
    0 => "test"
    1 => "test2"
  ]

is very simple, this is the mood index into my array $params

Comment: I try the question solution you link up, but i have the same problem, always empty array as result...

Comment: Just guessing here, but your relations seem to have overly complicated code. I mean, if I do `bin/console make:entity` and just follow prompts to add new `ManyToMany` relation, final code includes only something like `@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Mood", reversedBy="users")`, and that's all. More complex things (like in your code) I've been observing in a project were existing DB was "imported" to Doctrine, and in the end of the day I re-did all relations using `make:entity` because I had some problems (don't remember specifics). Maybe impor does not work that good for existing DBs.

Comment: @alx thx for your reply, i found a solution but your inspiration is very good, i will try make:entity functions as soon as possible ;) 
My problem was just in relation, i switch inverse id and now all is good, and i can retrieve all data i need ;)